# MongoDB $multiply operator PHP example?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to multiple all "point" fields.

```
$out = $kuponmac->aggregate(
      array('$match' => array('random'=>$random, 'ekleyen'=>$ekleyen)),
      array('$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$state',
                   'totalPop' => array('$multiply' => '$point')
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$match' => array('totalPop' => array('$gte' => 0))
            )
        );
```

this is my code. I'm trying to use multiply but I couldn't use it correctly.
How can I make multiplication  all "point" fields?

I'm looking http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/multiply/ but there's no detailed explanation or example.

could u help me?

Answer (score 1):

It says on the page how it works:

> Takes an array of one or more numbers and multiples them, returning the resulting product.

So you do:

```
array('$multiply' => array('$point', '$otherNumber'))
```

Since you cannot mulitply one number meaningfully.

Answer (score 1):

`$multiply` is not a supported [`$group` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/#group-operators) (unlike `$sum`), so you cannot used it in that context to compute the value for a grouped field. Instead, `$multiply` could be used in an expression, which may itself be included as an argument to a `$group` operator or as a field value in a projection.

I attempted to rewrite your pipeline as follows:

```
[
  { $group: { _id: "$state", points: { $push: "$point" }}},
  { $project: { product: { $multiply: "$points" }}}
]
```

The idea here is that we'd use [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) to collect all point values into an array for each state's `$group` projection, and then compute the product, using that array as the argument to `$multiply`.

Unfortunately, this resulted in an error, as MongoDB treated the de-referenced `points` field as a single argument to be multiplied, instead of an array of numbers. This was recently reported as a bug in [SERVER-10676](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10676). I'd encourage you to watch that issue for resolution.

Additionally, I opened [SERVER-10682](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10682) to discuss adding a `$product` operator for `$group`, which would be ideal for your use case.